# Python apply function on dataframe rows that write function output to columns in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame as shown below, and I want to apply a function that
calculates something with 'Value' and according to the result writes in one of the columns: A, B, C, D
The information about which result write in which column is in a dict

The problem is that the function doesn't write the wanted data to the dataframe. (using df.iterrows it worked but took a long time)

```
  date                flow      A   B   C   D  

0     2017-01-01 00:00:00  7185.0                                  
1     2017-01-01 00:15:00  7145.0                                   
2     2017-01-01 00:30:00  7135.0                                   
3     2017-01-01 00:45:00  7122.0                                  
4     2017-01-01 01:00:00  7142.0   


def my_func(row):
    low, high = nearest_neighbours(row) 

    if row['Flow'] > max(xp):
        col = [k for k, val in dict.iteritems() if value == max(dict.values())]
        row[col] = 0.25

    elif row['Flow'] == 0:
        row['A'] = 0.25

    else:
        col = [k for k, val in dict.iteritems() if value == low]
        row[col] = (high - row['Flow']) / (4 * (high - low))

        col = [k for k, val in dict.iteritems() if value == high]
        row[col] = (row['Flow'] - low) / (4 * (high - low))

df.apply(my_func,axis=1)
```

> Copy from comment:

I have a dict that look like:

```
{'A':3000, 'B':6000, 'C':9000 etc.}
```

I want to write some value in the columns `A-D` according to where the `'Flow'` value is relatively to the dict.
For example:

```
if Flow ==7500:
    # write some values in C and D
```

Comment: Please explain the logic behind your code, rather than having us interpret it

Comment: Could you please describe the output dataframe?

Comment: I have a dict that look like: {'A':3000, 'B':6000, 'C':9000 etc.}
I want to write some value in the columns A-D according to where the Flow value is relatively to the dict
for example if Flow ==7500, write some values in C and D